# We should remove the "Badges" link from here

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, meta

Since we don't have badges on this site.

Comment: there will be badges on meta-so

Comment: So make that an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: close? (no longer relevant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*puts on the joke hat*

Ok, ill get right on it. Gimme a sec.

[Here, how does this look.](http://cznp.com/minus_badges.png)

But yes I agree.

EDIT:

I read [somewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/we-should-remove-the-badges-link-from-here) that there will be badges on MSO. Here is my source, this is a quote from Jeff.

> there will be badges on meta-so – Jeff Atwood

`*giggles a little*`